# Counting number of map colorings in prolog

Tags: prolog, combinatorics

In prolog we can get a solution for a map coloring problem as follows:

```
different(red, green). different(red, blue). 
different(green, red). different(green, blue). 
different(blue, red). different(blue, green). 

coloring(Alabama, Mississippi, Georgia, Tennessee, Florida) :-
  different(Mississippi, Tennessee), 
  different(Mississippi, Alabama), 
  different(Alabama, Tennessee), 
  different(Alabama, Mississippi), 
  different(Alabama, Georgia), 
  different(Alabama, Florida), 
  different(Georgia, Florida), 
  different(Georgia, Tennessee). 

?- coloring(Alabama, Mississippi, Georgia, Tennessee, Florida).
Alabama = blue
Florida = green
Georgia = red
Mississippi = red
Tennessee = green
```

Is it possible to count the total number of possible map colorings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Anders solution, please note that the word 'colouring' should be in lower case, which will give the correct answer - 6 solutions.

```
aggregate_all(count, coloring(Alabama, Mississippi, Georgia, Tennessee, Florida), Count).
Count = 6.
```

Comment: Oh, good. I'm not crazy. I just posted a comment before seeing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) will enumerate all solutions, and (at least in SWI-Prolog) [aggregate_all/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=aggregate_all/3) can be used to perform a count:

```
?- aggregate_all(count, Coloring(A,M,G,T,F), Num).
Num = 4711.
```

Comment: Getting 4711 doesn't make sense. There are only 5^3 possible combinations including illegal combinations. Both computers I have run this on say 6 is the answer.

Comment: 4711 was just meant as an example of output from aggregate_all, I didn't have a prolog interpreter available to test-run your code. :-)